# Tkinter: AttributeError using .get()

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to retrieve a variable from a Tkinter Wiget but I am running into this error message:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Here is the widget code

```
JobNEntry = tkinter.Entry(menu, textvariable = tk.IntVar(JobNo))
JobNEntry.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky="W")
```

Here is the call code

```
JobNo=JobNo.get()
```

Also I need to know if the variable JobNo is writable to a file.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Like the error says, `JobNo` is an integer, and integers don't have a `get` method.

Comment: Okay, so can only strings be used with the get()  attribute.

Comment: `get()` is an attribute of some widgets of tkinter not basic variables like strings or ints. You need to use get on your entry widget most likely.

Comment: No, you can't use `get()` on strings, either. `get` is a method on some widgets (such as the `Entry` widget), and on `StringVar`, `IntVar`, `DoubleVar`, and `BooleanVar` objects.

Answer (score 2):

The `get()` method is part of several widgets in tkinter and is not something that you can use on a normal `int` or `str` object. `get()` must be called on a variable that is a widget object that has a `get()` method, like `Entry`.

Its likely you need to do:

```
JobNEntry.get()
```

This will get the current value from the entry field as a string.

If you want to save the value of that string you can. There are several tutorials on Stack Overflow and the web that go into detail on how to save a string to a file.

Looking at the code you have shown us, it's possible you have not created your `IntVar()` correctly.

Make sure you define the `IntVar()` first then set that variable as the `textvariable`.

Something like this:

```
JobNo = tk.IntVar()
JobNEntry = tkinter.Entry(menu, textvariable = JobNo)
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, however using it yields another error,this time    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_root'

Comment: @RipseedOil That is probably a completely separate issue. You need to provide your code in a new question with your imports and how you are creating your class / application.

Comment: @RipseedOil you will benefit from reading this post. [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and applying it to your questions going forward.

Answer (score 1):

The attribute error might be because you havnt already initialized the variable JobNo as an 'IntVar'

This is the code i have come up with :

```
import tkinter as tkinter

menu=tkinter.Tk()
JobNo=tkinter.IntVar()
JobNEntry = tkinter.Entry(menu, textvariable = JobNo)
JobNEntry.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky="W")
JobNo=JobNo.get()
menu.mainloop()
```

You need to initialize JobNo as an Integer Variable using IntVar()

```
JobNo=tkinter.IntVar()
```

And then use it in the Entrybox.
If you had some string to add to the entry, you should initialise as StringVar()
Also when you initialize, make sure you do it after opening the Tk window.(here i put it after menu=tkinter.Tk())

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def save_job_no():
    try:
        n = job_no.get()
    except TclError:
        status.config(text = "This is not an integer")
        return False
    status.config(text="")
    f = open("my_file.txt", "w")
    f.write(str(n))
    return True

root = Tk()

job_no = IntVar()
entry = ttk.Entry(root, width = 30, textvariable = job_no)
entry.grid()
label = ttk.Label(root, textvariable = job_no)
label.grid()
status = ttk.Label(root)
status.grid()
button = ttk.Button(root, text = "Write to a file", command = save_job_no)
button.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Code-only answers aren't very useful. It requires the reader to compare your code to the original code line-by-line and character-by-character. This answer would be much better if you explained what you changed before providing the code. In your case you didn't even use any of the OP's code so there's nothing to compare to. A beginner programmer will have no idea if the key to the solution is line 1, line 20, or any other line.