# How to add two StringVar() type of data in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Tkinter, I want to sum up the data which is collected from entry, where I am storing my text from entry in a textvariable which is of type StringVar(). I am facing a TypeError in adding the data. How do I proceed?

I have tried getting my text from the entry into IntVar() instead of StringVar(). But I am unable to sum/add the data.

```
bevaragesno=IntVar()
snacksno =IntVar()
chineseno =IntVar()
icecreamno =IntVar()
chatsno =IntVar()

sum=IntVar()
sum=bevaragesno.get()+snacksno.get()+chineseno.get()+icecreamno.get()+chatsno.get()
```

//txtpayslip is a textarea which I am using to display the sum

```
txtpayslip.insert(END,""+str(sum)+"\t\t"+total.get()+"\n")
```

\\
I am expecting to get the sum as my output

But I'm getting an error which says:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Please help with some alternative.

Comment: Can you check this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46223800/tkinter-attributeerror-using-get) , and let me know if it was useful.

Comment: Thank you, can you please provide a more relevant link? I was unable to understand the code.